# mode similar to highlight parentheses mode but which highlights keyword pairs in ruby(def end) (do end)

Tags: ruby, emacs

I'm looking for an emacs mode that highlights the keyword pairs in ruby - similar to the highlight parentheses mode for lisp languages.

I know than this exist for vim but I can't find a similar mode in emacs.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [ruby-block.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/ruby-block.el). Usage instructions are in the comments at the top of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [hrb-mode](https://github.com/ckruse/hrb-mode), which works exactly like `show-paren-mode`

Answer (score 0):

In Emacs-24.4, `show-paren-mode` should do just what you ask.